# remove fluent UI details List hover color issue

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui

I am using fluent ui detailsList.

[image]

I have two columns one have no header name. but its have row data. If I hover my mouse its highlighted. I need to remove that header highlight color. If someone have an idea please suggest me.

```
 {
  key: "title",
  name: "Title",
  fieldName: "title",
  minWidth: 150,
  maxWidth: 350,
  isRowHeader: true,
  isResizable: true,
  isSorted: false,
  isSortedDescending: false,
  onColumnClick: _onColumnClick,
  data: "string",
  isPadded: true,
},
{
  key: "moreOptions",
  ariaLabel: "TypeButtonColumn",
  minWidth: 70,
  maxWidth: 90,
  onRender: (item) => {
    return (
      <IconButton
        disabled={_setDisabled(item)}
        menuProps={menuProps(item)}
        menuIconProps={{ iconName: "More" }}
      />
    );
  },
},


        <div id="searchGrid" style={gridStyle}>
        <MarqueeSelection>
          <DetailsList
            items={tableItems}
            compact={false}
            columns={tableColumns}
            selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
            getKey={getKey}
            layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
            isHeaderVisible={true}
            selection={selection}
            selectionPreservedOnEmptyClick={true}
            enterModalSelectionOnTouch={true}
            ariaLabelForSelectionColumn="Toggle selection"
            ariaLabelForSelectAllCheckbox="Toggle selection for all items"
            checkButtonAriaLabel="select row"
            visibility="false"
          />
        </MarqueeSelection>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the examples shown in [Fluent UI's wiki page](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/wiki/Component-Styling#using-a-styleable-component), assign a custom styling object to the `styles` property of the column object you want to style.

```js
const columnHeaderStyles = {
  root: {
    selectors: {
      ":hover": {
        background: "white",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

In your case, assign it as

```js
{
  key: "moreOptions",
  ariaLabel: "TypeButtonColumn",
  minWidth: 70,
  maxWidth: 90,
  onRender: (item) => {
    return (
      <IconButton
        disabled={_setDisabled(item)}
        menuProps={menuProps(item)}
        menuIconProps={{ iconName: "More" }}
      />
    );
  },
  styles: columnHeaderStyles,
},
```